# Understanding Github Api Token Scope

Tags: github, github-api

I have setup an app via GitHub to use for a login auth flow after successful login it returns a token

I can then use this token to get information about myself.

I can’t however use this token to get repo collaborators for instance.

[https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/collaborators/${repo}/permission](https://api.github.com/repos/$%7Bowner%7D/$%7Brepo%7D/collaborators/$%7Brepo%7D/permission)

I have to use a personal access token generated via https://github.com/settings/tokens

Giving this token the correct permissions will allow me to check collaborators etc.

This token will be stored server side on my api so it will be hidden.

My flow is like this.

1. Authenticate on my website using my GitHub app.
2. Send the auth token to my api
3. Check collaborator access
4. If they have access allow login

Here is the api logic

```
const getUser = await fetch("https://api.github.com/user", {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `token ${access_token}`, // sent from website
    },
});
const user = await getUser.json();

const checkPermissions = await fetch(
    `https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/collaborators/${user.login}/permission`, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `token gho_personal-access-token`,
        },
    }
);
const permissions = await checkPermissions.json();

if (
    permissions.permission && ["admin", "write"].includes(permissions.permission)
) {
    return res.status(200).json(user);
} else {
    return res.status(400).json("Access denied");
}
```

The problem I have is my personal access token that I have created has access to all my repos which doesn’t seem secure.

Also if I am in a team they would never allow this having a token with any read write access to all company repos is really dangerous even if its on a secure server.

What is best practice to limit access to a personal access token to a single repo.

I have seen Deploy keys but these are not https they do not work for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

In Nov. 2022, GitHub did [introduce fine-grained personal access tokens for GitHub](https://github.blog/2022-10-18-introducing-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens-for-github/)

> Fine-grained personal access tokens give developers granular control over the permissions and repository access they grant to a PAT.
> Organization administrators are in control too, with approval policies and full visibility for tokens that access organization resources.
>
> Fine-grained personal access tokens, by contrast, are given permissions from a set of **[over 50 granular permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens)** that control access to GitHub’s organization, user, and repository APIs.
>
> Each permission can be granted on a ‘no access’, ‘read’ or ‘read and write’ basis.
> As an example, you can now create a PAT that can only read issues and do nothing else – not even read the contents of a repository.

And you can limit a fine-grained token to a specific repository if you need to.

See "[Creating a fine-grained personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-fine-grained-personal-access-token)".